# Core Data Fetch Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a datamodel that looks like this:

[image]

I show a list of Customers on a tableview, when the user selects a customer, it then shows a list of rooms for that customer - this all currently works fine.

The problem i am getting is when i try and show a detail view for the Room. When the user selects a room, it shows a view with all the values of that room. (well should do). I have this working to some extent, BUT if i have two rooms named the same ie - "Bedroom 1", for two different customers then it doesnt show the correct room data.

here is the code i am using:

```
AppDelegate_Shared *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Rooms" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Room = %@)", titleStr];

    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if ([objects count] == 0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"No matches");
    } else 
    {
        matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"matches found");
        aLbl.text = [matches valueForKey:@"DimA"];
    }
    [request release];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];  
    [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
```

What i want to happen, is the detail view shows the details based on what customer is already chosen.

Any help is much appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your predicate to also include the Customer you are searching for.

Imagine this is SQL (assuming you have used SQL), the predicate is your WHERE clause. If Room isn't unique, then this will return all rooms with the same name.

What you want is rooms where ROOM == roomName and customer == customerId.

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Room == %@)AND(CustomerRelationship==%@)", titleStr, customerManagedObject]